# directly perform a selector on a object

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have a selector:

```
(SEL)aSelector
```

and, I have an object `MyObj`.

The `aSelector` represents a function defined in the class of `MyObj`.

**How can I perform the selector on** `MyObj`**?**

(I found in NSObject class, there is a function:

[- performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:)

But it doesn't fit what I need, since the `withObject:` part there represents a parameter pass to the selector function, but what I need is to send selector message to this `myObj`)

**===== Why I ask & What I want to achieve ===**

I want to have a general function which accepts a Selector type parameter and a object on which the selector is supposed to perform. In this general function body, I use dispatch group to perform this selector on the object and wait for the selector function complete, my code snippet:

```
-(void)myGeneralFuncWithObject:(NSObject*)myObj andSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
  ...
  dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    // My question is how to write code to 
    // indicate performing aSelector on myObj here?
  });

  dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
     // selector function finished here, I suppose.
  });
}
```

**CLARIFICATION:**

I'd like to perform  the selector on `myObj`, like I mentioned above. The class of `myObj` is also a subclass of `NSThread`, and I would like the selector to perform on this thread. So, in total, I want the selector to be performed on `myObj` and on `myObj` thread. That's all about it.

Comment: can you explain in a little more detail what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Zartha, please see my update.

Comment: So you just want to call a method with no arguments? Then pass `nil` into the `withObject:` parameter. I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: @originaluser2 , I am not saying call method without arguments, it could have arguments of course, but for simplification, in my question, I use a selector without argument, but that is not the point of my question anyhow. I just want to know in objective-c is there a way to perform a selector on an object whose class has defined a function represented by that selector.

Comment: I didn't manage to understand you question.. Are you trying to pass an object a selector? Or perform on an object the selector? And If your trying to perform the selecor, I do not understand why "perfromSelector:onMainThread:WithObject:" Isn't good for you.. Can you try to explain better?

Comment: @PiratM , `myObj` is a object of NSThread class, and I want the selector to be performed on myObj thread as well.

Comment: @Leem.fin myObj is a object of NSThread? It inherits from NSThreas? Or you just want to perfrom the selector from the current thread?

Comment: @Leem.fin `myObj` is an `NSThread`? In the question you say `myObj` is the object you want to call the selector on, not the thread you want it to be performed on. This question needs a lot of clarifying – please could you edit the OP and focus on the exact problem you're having.

Comment: @originaluser2, I'd like to perform  the selector on `myObj`, like I mentioned in my question. I just added that `myObj`'s class is also a subclass of NSThread, and I would like the selector to perform on this thread. So, in total, I want the selector to be performed on myObj and on myObj thread. That's all about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this 
In MyObj.h

```
-(void)mySelWithOneArgument:(MyObj*)argument;
```

In MyObj.m

```
-(void)mySelWithOneArgument:(MyObj*)argument{
     //Do whateve
}
```

Now in your general function do this

```
-(void)myGeneralFuncWithObject:(NSObject*)myObj andSelector:   
(SEL)aSelector{
 ...
 dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
      [myObj performSelector:aSelector withObject:myObj];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
 // selector function finished here, I suppose.
});
}
```

And 
`aSelector = @selector(mySelWithOneArgument:);//Dont forget the : at the end`

Comment: I get "undefined selector" error when calling my general function , because I am calling from another class not from MyObj class. How to get rid of it?

Comment: No matter where are you calling from it should work. Can you post your code how are you calling in the comment?

Comment: I call it like this `[self myGeneralFuncWithObject:myObj andSelector:@(doTask:) withArgument:(NSString*)name]` , the `doTask:(NSString*)name` is a function defined in myObj class.

Comment: OK, I see, I should use @selector() but I was using @() for the selector part

Comment: Yes thats correct. Just to clarify you wanted to do this "How can I perform the selector on MyObj" but this selector of yours "doTask:(NSString*)name" takes string as an argument not instance of MyObj.

Comment: yes, exactly. Though in my original post, I said no argument pass needed, but that is only for simplify my code in question. In practice there could have a scenario with argument. Thanks, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyClass : NSThread
-(void)myGeneralFuncWithObject:(MyClass*)myObj andSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
@end
@implementation MyClass

- (void)myMethod:(MyClass *)object {
    NSLog(@"%@", object);
}

-(void)myGeneralFuncWithObject:(MyClass*)myObj andSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
    if ([myObj respondsToSelector:aSelector]){
        [myObj performSelector:aSelector withObject:myObj];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Class not have selector");
    }
}

@end
```

if I understand correctly

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [myClass myGeneralFuncWithObject:myClass andSelector:@selector(myMethod:)];
```

Comment: `[myObj performSelector:aSelector withObject:myObj];` one questions on this, why you pass myObj as argument to the selector?

Comment: @Leem.fin, in this case for clarity and example.

Comment: @Leem.fin, as a parameter (myObj) could be any other object class having a selector (aSelector)

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer for trying to perform selector on the MyObject, and that MyObject is subclass of NSThread, and the selector should perform on that thread.
I hope this is what you meant.

```
 -(void)myGeneralFuncWithObject:(NSObject*)myObj andSelector:(SEL)aSelector{

        NSThread *thread = (NSThread *)myObj;
        [myObj performSelector:aSelector onThread:thread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```